# Django "name_istartswith" is not case-insensitive for me

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I tested it with the console.

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from myapp.models import Product
>>>
>>> p = Product.objects.all()[0]
>>> print p.name
>>> 'Chia Seeds'
>>> p = Product.objects.filter(name__istartswith='chia s')
>>> print p
>>> []
```

Using Django-Trunk (1.4a1) and MySQL 5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1

**Is it a problem of MySQL**? Or what else?

Comment: what does `str( Product.objects.filter(name__istartswith='chia s').query)` output? what happens if you run that in a `dbshell`?

Comment: @second it uses "LIKES" instead of "ILIKES" as stated in the link provided by akonsu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is discussed here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9682
I myself never used MySQl so I do  not know for sure, but it seems that you need to use an appropriate database collation setting for this to work.

Comment: this looks like one of those annoying things of django :-(

Comment: I have the same problem with SQLite when using cyrillic letters. istartswith and icontains do not correctly hadle queries. They are case-sensitive, though when i use latin letters, everything is OK.